# what is the difference among noise,blurring and contrast?

Tags: noise, image-processing

I want to know the following
what is the difference among noise,blurring and contrast ?

Comment: That is an unhelpful and innacurate comment. Anyone can list hundreds differences between a giraffe and banane (size, weight, shape, colors, movement, taste, odor, sounds it makes, solidity, texture…).